# javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException:Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich, but no tag was defined for name: button

Tags: jsf, tomcat7, tomcat6, jsf-2.2, oracle-adf

I configured my Tomcat environment and I successfully deployed ADF Essentials onto Tomcat6.x that was developed using Jdeveloper11.1.2.4 .

Now I am trying to deploy a sample ADF web application (that contains only one page with a button in that) developed using Jdeveloper12c onto Tomcat 6.x and Tomcat 7.X. On both of the servers am getting the following exception

```
type Exception report

message /M.jsf @15,81 <af:button> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich, but no tag was defined for name: button

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: /M.jsf @15,81 <af:button> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich, but no tag was defined for name: button
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:514)
    oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFFilter.doFilter(ServletADFFilter.java:65)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /M.jsf @15,81 <af:button> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich, but no tag was defined for name: button
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:291)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:232)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:355)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2778)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:392)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:368)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:297)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:92)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:162)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:160)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:83)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:78)
    com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:119)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:248)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:193)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:741)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.buildView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:341)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:990)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:342)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:236)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:509)
    oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFFilter.doFilter(ServletADFFilter.java:65)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

After this I have deleted button from that page and I added an `<af:outputText value="outputText1" id="ot1"/>`. Now this page is successfully running on Tomcat7.x.

Please help me. Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Seems like your tag libraries when deploying on Tomcat are one version older than the ones corresponding to your Weblogic deployment. af:button is a tag coming with newest ADF version, while af:outputText is been there for quite few versions back already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDeveloper 11.1.x.x then there is nothing called button, it's either called af:commandButton or af:goButton.

In 12c These two buttons has been replaced with af:button which can act as af:commandButton or af:goButton depending on it's attribute. Since you downgraded from 12c to 11g, you need to take care of these and use the equivalent button. Also af:commandButton and af:goButton works in 12c for Backward compatibility, so you should be okay to use them with 12c although not recommended.